# How to compute and store the digits of sqrt(n) up to 10^6 decimal places?

Tags: algorithm, math, decimal, sqrt

I am doing research work. for which I need to compute and store the square root of 2 up to 10^6 places. I have googled for this but I got only a NASA page but how they computed that I don't know. I used set_precision of c++. but that is giving the result up to around 50 places only.what should I do?

NASA page link: https://apod.nasa.gov/htmltest/gifcity/sqrt2.1mil
I have tried binary search also but not fruitful.

```
long double ans = sqrt(n);
cout<<fixed<<setprecision(50)<<ans<<endl;
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Do you want only an algorithm (as in your tag) or do you want code? Do you want the answer to use C++ or is another language also appropriate? Could the answer use a library or do you want base code?

Comment: Anything wrong with Newton's iterations ?

Comment: You need to use an arbitrary precision math library to compute something to that level of precision.  Long double is only 80 bits long which can only give you 15-18 digits of precision. Setprecision only determines rounding for display, not the underlying calculation.

Comment: What people do is to pick a series representation, like [these](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Square_root_of_2#Series_and_product_representations), that converges as fast as possible, like the last one in that list. The computations need to be done on a type that can store all the digits required. Don't use Newton's method. You would need to do divisions of <strike>large</strike> long numbers at every step.

Comment: Its continued fraction [is also very simple](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Square_root_of_2#Continued_fraction_representation). This yields also a simple method to compute it. It is equivalent to compute it using an alternating series, though. I think the series above converges faster, and for the continued fraction you would need to know or get the explanation of how to use it.

Comment: Related https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15362117/find-as-many-digits-of-the-square-root-of-2-as-possible

Comment: Search for "spigot algorithm sqrt(2)". Spigot algorithms are algorithms to compute digits (of various numbers) in a number of operations which is proportional to the number of digits, so computing the n'th digit isn't more expensive than the first; the algorithm is like spigot that pours out digits.

Comment: @RobertDodier For `sqrt(2)` there might not be such an algorithm at hand. At least, it might not be known [if it has one of the types of series that yields computing digits without computing all previous ones](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Square_root_of_2#Series_and_product_representations). See the comment following the second to last series.

Comment: How fast do you need this to be? FWIW, `y = math.isqrt(2*10**2000000)` takes under 10 seconds with Python 3.8 on my laptop. Converting the answer to a decimal takes around another 10 seconds.

Comment: @MarkDickinson My computer sucks! It is still calculating that. What do you have? It could also be the implementation of `isqrt`. I am using `isqrt-0.9.2.0` for Python3.7.

Comment: Please could you clarify your requirements, as in @RoryDaulton's comment?

Comment: @conditionalMethod: Ah, no. I'm using `math.isqrt` in the Python std. lib., which is new in Python 3.8 (which, strictly speaking, hasn't been released yet). BTW, the claim that "The running time is linear time in the bit length of the integer." for the PyPI isqrt package is demonstrably false.

Comment: Good to know. It looks like that they made a much better implementation. So much better that this thing is still running and nothing.

Comment: @RoryDaulton  Yes, any language, library will be appropriate. only thing is I have to store each and every digit (up to 1000000).

Comment: @YvesDaoust yes, newtons iterations give approximate result.

Comment: @conditionalMethod can you please explain the division method?

Comment: @pandey So you already have the digits you need from the NASA page. Can you explain what you're looking for beyond that - i.e., why that existing solution doesn't satisfy your needs? (FWIW, I checked that the Python `math.isqrt`-based solution gives the exact same digits as are on that page.)

Comment: @MarkDickinson I forgot to say you thankyou. Actually I was finding it for every n. That is why I was not copying it from the NASA page. 
I code in c++. Now I am using python also. python is good at this type of problems.

Answer (score 1):

You have various options here. You can work with an arbitrary-precision floating-point library (for example [MPFR](https://www.mpfr.org) with C or C++, or [mpmath](http://mpmath.org) or the built-in [decimal](https://docs.python.org/3/library/decimal.html) library in Python). Provided you know what error guarantees that library gives, you can ensure that you get the correct decimal digits. For example, both MPFR and Python's `decimal` guarantee correct rounding here, but MPFR has the disadvantage (for your particular use-case of getting *decimal* digits) that it works in binary, so you'd also need to analyse the error induced by the binary-to-decimal conversion.

You can also work with pure integer methods, using an arbitrary-precision integer library (like [GMP](https://gmplib.org)), or a language that supports arbitrary-precision integers out of the box (for example, Java with its BigInteger class: recent versions of Java provide a [`BigInteger.sqrt`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/math/BigInteger.html#sqrt()) method): scale `2` by `10**2n`, where `n` is the number of places after the decimal point that you need, take the *integer* square root (i.e., the integer part of the exact mathematical square root), and then scale back by `10**n`. See below for a relatively simple but efficient algorithm for computing integer square roots.

The simplest out-of-the-box option here, if you're willing to use another language, is to use Python's `decimal` library. Here's all the code you need, assuming Python 3 (not Python 2, where this will be horribly slow).

```
>>> from decimal import Decimal, getcontext
>>> getcontext().prec = 10**6 + 1  # number of significant digits needed
>>> sqrt2_digits = str(Decimal(2).sqrt())
```

The `str(Decimal(2).sqrt())` operation takes less than 10 seconds on my machine. Let's check the length, and the first and last hundred digits (we obviously can't reproduce the whole output here):

```
>>> len(sqrt2_digits)
1000002
>>> sqrt2_digits[:100]
'1.41421356237309504880168872420969807856967187537694807317667973799073247846210703885038753432764157'
>>> sqrt2_digits[-100:]
'2637136344700072631923515210207475200984587509349804012374947972946621229489938420441930169048412044'
```

There's a slight problem with this: the result *is* guaranteed to be correctly rounded, but that's *rounded*, not *truncated*. So that means that that final "4" digit could be the result of a final round *up* - that is, the actual digit in that position could be a "3", with an "8" or "9" (for example) following it.

We can get around this by computing a couple of extra digits, and then truncating them (after double checking that rounding of *those* extra digits doesn't affect the truncation).

```
>>> getcontext().prec = 10**6 + 3
>>> sqrt2_digits = str(Decimal(2).sqrt())
>>> sqrt2_digits[-102:]
'263713634470007263192351521020747520098458750934980401237494797294662122948993842044193016904841204391'
```

So indeed the millionth digit after the decimal point is a 3, not a 4. Note that if the last 3 digits computed above had been "400", we still wouldn't have known whether the millionth digit was a "3" or a "4", since that "400" could again be the result of a round up. In that case, you could compute *another* two digits and try again, and so on, stopping when you have an unambiguous output. (For further reading, search for "The table maker's dilemma".)

(Note that setting the `decimal` module's rounding mode to `ROUND_DOWN` does *not* work here, since the `Decimal.sqrt` method ignores the rounding mode.)

If you want to do this using pure integer arithmetic, Python 3.8 offers a `math.isqrt` function for computing exact integer square roots. In this case, we'd use it as follows:

```
>>> from math import isqrt
>>> sqrt2_digits = str(isqrt(2*10**(2*10**6)))
```

This takes a little longer: around 20 seconds on my laptop. Half of that time is for the binary-to-decimal conversion implicit in the `str` call. But this time, we got the truncated result directly, and didn't have to worry about the possibility of rounding giving us the wrong final digit(s).

Examining the results again:

```
>>> len(sqrt2_digits)
1000001
>>> sqrt2_digits[:100]
'1414213562373095048801688724209698078569671875376948073176679737990732478462107038850387534327641572'
>>> sqrt2_digits[-100:]
'2637136344700072631923515210207475200984587509349804012374947972946621229489938420441930169048412043'
```

This is a bit of a cheat, because (at the time of writing) Python 3.8 hasn't been released yet, although beta versions [are available](https://www.python.org/downloads/release/python-380b4/). But there's a pure Python version of the `isqrt` algorithm in the [CPython source](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/d93605de7232da5e6a182fd1d5c220639e900159/Modules/mathmodule.c#L1515-L1535), that you can copy and paste and use directly. Here it is in full:

```
import operator

def isqrt(n):
    """
    Return the integer part of the square root of the input.
    """
    n = operator.index(n)

    if n < 0:
        raise ValueError("isqrt() argument must be nonnegative")
    if n == 0:
        return 0

    c = (n.bit_length() - 1) // 2
    a = 1
    d = 0
    for s in reversed(range(c.bit_length())):
        # Loop invariant: (a-1)**2 < (n >> 2*(c - d)) < (a+1)**2
        e = d
        d = c >> s
        a = (a << d - e - 1) + (n >> 2*c - e - d + 1) // a

    return a - (a*a > n)
```

The source also contains an explanation of the above algorithm and an informal proof of its correctness.

You can check that the results by the two methods above agree (modulo the extra decimal point in the first result). They're computed by completely different methods, so that acts as a sanity check on both methods.

Answer (score 0):

You could use big integers, e.g. BigInteger in Java. Then you calculate the square root of 2e12 or 2e14. Note that sqrt(2) = 1.4142... and sqrt(200) = 14.142... Then you can use the Babylonian method to get all the digits: E.g. S = 10^14. x(n+1) = (x(n) + S / x(n)) / 2. Repeat until x(n) doesn't change. Maybe there are more efficient algorithms that converge faster.

Comment: The result would be around 10^6, not the number of digits,  you would have to take 2 * 10^(10^12), which is incredibly big.

Comment: `2 * 10^(2 * 10^6)` is enough, and that's small enough to effectively compute an integer square root.

Comment: @maraca  this gives an approximate result. In research, I have to work on exact values.

Comment: @pandey it is an approximation, which can reach arbritrary precision, you just have to do enough iterations. No problem to find the first X digits of some root. For pi and e it is done the same way.

Answer (score 0):

```js
// Input: a positive integer, the number of precise digits after the decimal point
// Output: a string representing the long float square root

function findSquareRoot(number, numDigits) {
    function get_power(x, y) {
      let result = 1n;
      for (let i = 0; i < y; i ++) {
        result = result * BigInt(x);
      }
      return result;
    }

    let a = 5n * BigInt(number);
    let b = 5n;
    const precision_digits = get_power(10, numDigits + 1);

    while (b < precision_digits) {
      if (a >= b) {
        a = a - b;
        b = b + 10n;
      } else {
        a = a * 100n;
        b = (b / 10n) * 100n + 5n;
      }
    }

    let decimal_pos = Math.floor(Math.log10(number))
    if (decimal_pos == 0) decimal_pos = 1
    let result = (b / 100n).toString()
    result = result.slice(0, decimal_pos) + '.' + result.slice(decimal_pos)    
    return result
  }
```