# How can I get the square root for a very large integer?

Tags: c

I need to determine x from the expression root(y).

"Y" has a range to its separated value with maximum 10^1000.
I solved it in the normal way and I saw the right result. But when Y is very large, the program outputs the wrong answer.

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<math.h>
int main()
{
    long long int x,y;
    scanf("%lld",&y);
    x=sqrt(y);
    printf("%lld",x);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: the idea of this problem, that you are to implement the sqrt yourself for big numbers.

Comment: 676=4*169=(2^2)*(13^13)=22^132
, Therefore 
√676=√(4⋅169)=√2^2 * √13^2 = 26

Comment: If you really want to do numbers as large as `10^1000` then `long long` is no where near large enough.

Comment: @FirstStep and suppose √Y is prime?

Comment: `sqrt` is a floating point function, not an integer.

Comment: [Unums](http://www.johngustafson.net/unums.html) bear some interesting implications for this problem, but the implementation would be far too complex (and possibly not worth the time for this specific case?) to warrant an official answer to that effect.

Comment: Related: [square root of bignum using GMP](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/822734/square-root-of-bignum-using-gmp)

Comment: There are roughly 10 binary digits for every 3 decimal digits (as 2^10 is about the same as 10^3). So 10^1000 is roughly 2^3000. You would need more than 45 64-bit words to store a 10^1000.  You need to learn to walk before you can run. I would start off implementing sqrt of two 64-bit words (128-bit integer) first and then generalize to multi-word sqrt.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use some bignum library, for example [GMP](https://gmplib.org/)

Comment: I also feel this answer is a bit sparse, but I'm not entirely sure what more could be added...